# Send double tap to SCNView

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

SCNView build camera control has a function,double tap sceneview and roll back camera to start position when allowsCameraControl is enabled.

i went to add a button do the same thing

when user click the button i will roll back camera to start position

there is no class implement UIControl in scenekit

so i can't use sendAction

i can set camera position by scnView.pointOfView

but there is a animation when user scroll the camera, set camera position will fail when animation is running.

is there a good way to reset the camera ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NicoS's answer effectively handles the part of your question about making a user action change the camera POV.

As for your issue with undesired animation when setting `pointOfView` — you can control that animation (and any other implicit animations that happen when you change object properties) using the [`SCNTransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scntransaction) class. To make a change with no animation, just do this (Swift 3):

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0
// perform your changes...
view.pointOfView = newCameraNode
// ...and anything else you want to happen in the same non-animated update, then...
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: this is the answer i went!! thanks, now camera can rollback, and allowsCameraControl is working too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a TapGestureRecognizer to your Storyboard, to the view that has the SCNView. Connect the gesture recognizer action to your class so that you have an IBAction. Set the number of taps to two taps in the Storyboard Attributes Inspector. Now you can add your code to reset the camera.

Comment: this tap can not call the double tap event inside scnview.allowsCameraControl.